# SQLalchemy not find table for creating foreign key

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have a problem with SQL Alchemy, while trying to create a database, i get:

```
"sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'estate_agent.person_id' could not find table 'person' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'"
```

Meta datas:

```
db = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2:...//')
meta = MetaData()
meta.bind = db
```

Person table:

```
tbl_person = Table(
   'person', meta,
   Column('id', Integer, Sequence('seq_person_id'), primary_key=True),
   Column('name', String(100), unique=True, nullable = False),
   Column('password', String(40), nullable = False),
   Column('person_type_id', Integer, ForeignKey("person_type.id"), nullable = False),
   Column('register_date', DateTime, default = datetime.now),
   Column('pendencies', String(200)),
   Column('active', Boolean, default = True),
   schema = 'public')
```

Bug Table:

```
tbl_estate_agent = Table(
   'estate_agent', meta,
   Column('person_id', Integer, ForeignKey("person.id"), primary_key = True),
   Column('prize_range_id', Integer, ForeignKey("prize_range.id"), nullable = False),
   schema = 'public')
```

Normal table (creating normally the fk)

```
tbl_person_agent = Table(
   'person_agent', meta,
   Column('person_id', Integer, ForeignKey("person.id"), primary_key = True),
   Column('prize_range_id', Integer, ForeignKey("prize_range.id"), nullable = False),
   schema = 'public')
```

Creation Call:

```
meta.create_all(checkfirst=True)
```

Complete error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "database_client.py", line 159, in <module>
    meta.create_all(checkfirst=True)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 3404, in create_all
    tables=tables)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1616, in _run_visitor
    conn._run_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1245, in _run_visitor
    **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 120, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 699, in visit_metadata
    collection = [t for t in sort_tables(tables)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 862, in sort_tables
    {'foreign_key': visit_foreign_key})
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 256, in traverse
    return traverse_using(iterate(obj, opts), obj, visitors)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 247, in traverse_using
    meth(target)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 853, in visit_foreign_key
    parent_table = fkey.column.table   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 725, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 1720, in column tablekey)
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'estate_agent.person_id' could not find table 'person' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By adding the following line to my `parent` table solved my problem. In case of Declarative:

```
children = relationship("Child")
```

Otherwise: [SQLAlchemy - Classic Mapper](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_styles.html#classical-mappings)

Also try to have a look in [here (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046039/sqlalchemy-import-tables-with-relationships) too, might help.

Answer (score 79):

The solution is to replace the strings with actual columns:

```
Column('person_id', Integer, ForeignKey(tbl_person.c.id), primary_key=True)
```

Comment: @Icyh Late to the party, but it works because you must import the `Table` object, which means it is actually created. I'm willing to bet that in the original code the `tbl_person` had not been created and so the string lookup fails, because the `MetaData` did not contain it.

Comment: Thanks, this still worked for me. Not sure why because parts of the code still work with ' ' but works. :)

Answer (score 20):

In case of Declarative, I solved this problem by simply importing the class that was 'could not be found'.

Answer (score 12):

Although the top voted answer solves the issue, replacing strings with objects forces you to define tables in a specific order (which can be non-trivial for very large databases). From the [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/constraints.html#defining-foreign-keys):

> The advantage to using a string is that the in-python linkage between [different tables] is resolved only when first needed, so that table objects can be easily spread across multiple modules and defined in any order.

You can continue to use strings by passing the schema to the `ForeignKey`. For example, instead of doing:

```py
tbl_estate_agent = Table(
   'estate_agent', meta,
   Column('person_id', Integer, ForeignKey("person.id"), primary_key = True),
   Column('prize_range_id', Integer, ForeignKey("prize_range.id"), nullable = False),
   schema = 'public')
```

One can do:

```py
tbl_estate_agent = Table(
   'estate_agent', meta,
   Column('person_id', Integer, ForeignKey("public.person.id"), primary_key = True),
   Column('prize_range_id', Integer, ForeignKey("public.prize_range.id"), nullable = False),
   schema = 'public')
```

Comment: excellent - this was the missing piece for me

Comment: It worked here. Specially because I was not using the default schema perhaps. Thanks man

Answer (score 7):

#### Conclusion

This exception was caused because that there is no record of parent table in *MetaData* instance, and this table needs to be retrieved in the DB.
Invoke the function "reflect" of class *MetaData* to obtain all existed tables on the DB. It should be used like this

```py
def upgrade(migrate_engine):

    meta.bind = migrate_engine

    meta.reflect() # <------ Obtain all tables here.

    aggregate_metadata.create()
    aggregate_hosts.create()
```

#### Description

A table is in a different file from another table that has a foreign key associate with it.
In this case, *sqlalchemy* will fail to find the corresponding table when create tables, as shown below:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'aggregate_metadata.aggregate_id' could not find table 'aggregates' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'

For example:

```py
# File 002_Add_aggregates_table.py
# ========================================
...

meta = MetaData()

aggregates = Table('aggregates', meta,
    ...
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    mysql_engine='InnoDB',
    mysql_charset='utf8'
)

def upgrade(migrate_engine):
    meta.bind = migrate_engine
    aggregates.create()
```

```py
# File 003_Add_aggregate_metadata_hosts.py
# ========================================
...

meta = MetaData()

aggregate_metadata = Table('aggregate_metadata', meta,
    ...
    Column('aggregate_id', Integer, ForeignKey('aggregates.id'), # <------ ForeignKey
           nullable=False),
    mysql_engine='InnoDB',
    mysql_charset='utf8'
    )

def upgrade(migrate_engine):

    meta.bind = migrate_engine
    aggregate_metadata.create()
```

#### Root cause

Let's locate at the point that throw the exception

```
  File "/opt/xxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1113, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/opt/xxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 2394, in column
    tablekey,
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'aggregate_metadata.aggregate_id' could not find table 'aggregates' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

We could find the corresponding code and debug it:

```
# File: sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py
2358     def column(self):
            ...
2371
2372        if isinstance(self._colspec, util.string_types):
2373
2374           parenttable, tablekey, colname = self._resolve_col_tokens()

# =========> BeginDebug
2375           raise Exception(
2376               'imgrass->\n'
2377               '  - parenttable: %s\n'
2378               '  - parenttable.metadata: %s\n'
2379               '  - tablekey: %s\n'
2380               '  - colname: %s' % (
2381                   parenttable,
2382                   parenttable.metadata,
2383                   tablekey,
2384                   colname
2385                   )
2386               )
# =========> EndDebug

2387
2388           if tablekey not in parenttable.metadata:
2389              raise exc.NoReferencedTableError(
2390                 "Foreign key associated with column '%s' could not find "
2391                 "table '%s' with which to generate a "
2392                 "foreign key to target column '%s'"
2393                 % (self.parent, tablekey, colname),
2394                 tablekey,
2395              )
```

Then we could get below exceptions:

```
Exception: imgrass->
  - parenttable: aggregate_metadata
  - parenttable.metadata: MetaData(bind=Engine(mysql+pymysql://imgrass:***@172.17.0.1/demo))
  - tablekey: aggregates
  - colname: id
```

So, the *parenttable.metadata* is an instance of class *MetaData*, and the *tablekey* is a table name.
We could reasonably guess that the table *aggregates* should be included in the instance of class *MetaData*.
Considering that the definition of this table is in another file, and the *MetaData* instance has the connection way of DB(bind=xxx), there should be a function in class *MetaData* to obtain all tables in the DB.

In MetaData, we could find this function

```py
# File: sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py

class MetaData(SchemaItem):
    ...

    def reflect(...):
        r"""Load all available table definitions from the database.
        ...
```

From its description, we could guess its function, let's apply it in my script:

```py
# File 003_Add_aggregate_metadata_hosts.py
# ========================================
...

def upgrade(migrate_engine):

    meta.bind = migrate_engine

# ==================> BeginUpdate
    meta.reflect()
# ==================> EndUpdate

    aggregate_metadata.create()
    aggregate_hosts.create()
```

It's okay!

Comment: This answer is underrated. It shows the real problem here and describes how to properly handle it.