# Problems with initial migrations with Alembic while creating tables with foreign key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, alembic

I am creating web backend with FastAPI and using Alembic to make my migrations. I've created my models inhereting them from `DeclarativeBase` of SQLAlchemy ORM. But when I try to create migrations with Alembic I get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'airport.country_id' could not find table 'country' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

I've searched the internet on what might be the cause of this. I've seen [advices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28047027/sqlalchemy-not-find-table-for-creating-foreign-key) on adding the name of the schema to the table name in the parent column, which didn't work. In the same question they advice on adding `meta.reflect()` to `upgrade()` function. But my migrations file does not even get created, so nowhere to put this. Maybe, there is something wrong with declaration of my models, here they are:

airport.py

```
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Airport(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'airport'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    iata_short: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(5))
    icao_short: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(5))
    timezone: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(5))

    country_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('country.id'))
    country: Mapped['Country'] = relationship(back_populates='airports')

    departure_reservations: Mapped[List["Reservation"]] = relationship(back_populates='departure_airport')
    arrival_reservations: Mapped[List["Reservation"]] = relationship(back_populates='arrival_airport')
```

country.py

```
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Country(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'country'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(20))
    continent: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(20))
    currencty: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(3))

    airports: Mapped[List['Airport']] = relationship(back_populates='country')
```

This is how I imported them to my env.py:

```
from models import (
    aircraft_type, 
    airline,
    airport,
    country,
    reservation,
    tariff,
    user
)
target_metadata = [
    aircraft_type.Base.metadata, 
    airline.Base.metadata,
    country.Base.metadata,
    airport.Base.metadata,
    reservation.Base.metadata,
    tariff.Base.metadata,
    user.Base.metadata
]
```

I also found out that while creating migrations Alembic connects to my PostgreSQL server.
Isn't it supposed to connect only while applying migrations?

Please tell what can cause this behaviour and what I did wrong.
Feel free to ask for any additional data!

Comment: You have to use the same `Base`, do not create new ones in each file. Have a common `Base` per app, import that and use it in all your models, that should fix it, hopefully

Comment: @python_user That worked, tysm! Now I get `Duplicate table keys across multiple MetaData objects` error. Is it caused by my tables all having field named `id`? Do I change it to something unique?

Comment: Can you change `target_metadata` such that it looks like this `target_metadata = Base.metadata`, `Base` is the common base you imported and use in your app

Comment: @python_user Well, migrations came out empty. I've created base.py, with nothing more than creation of `Base` class, then imported this class to all the files with my models. Created `__init__.py`, imported `Base` there, then imported it into my `env.py`. Maybe I've missed something about connecting `Base` with my models?

Comment: the most straightforward fix I can think of is is to import your models (`from app.country import Country`, `from app.airport import Airport`) in env.py, then do the change I suggested in my second comment. You will not use the imported models anywhere, that is fine, but importing them there is needed for this to work

Comment: @python_user yeah everything worked thank you very much!

Comment: @python_user yeah sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'airport.country_id' could not find table 'country' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

You get that error because you are creating different `Base` for different models. Typically, one `Base` per app is what is used. You can create something like the following and use this throughout your apps.

common.py

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass
```

airport.py

```
from common import Base

class Airport(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'airport'
```

country.py

```
from common import Base

class Country(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'country'
```

As for the next error in you mention in the comments.

`Duplicate table keys across multiple MetaData objects`

In `env.py` make the following changes.

```
# import the same common base you used across your app
from common import Base

# import all the models, they will not be used anywhere in this file, but they have to be imported
# for alembic (sqlalchemy) to know they exist.
# This step may not be needed depending on your project structure, 
# but importing them here is a sure way to make sure your models are picked up by alembic (sqlalchemy).
from models import (
    aircraft_type, 
    airline,
    airport,
    country,
    reservation,
    tariff,
    user
)

# you were using a list here
target_metadata = Base.metadata
```

Regarding your other question.

> I also found out that while creating migrations Alembic connects to my PostgreSQL server. Isn't it supposed to connect only while applying migrations?

I think [Offline Mode](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/offline.html) might be what you want.