# SQLAlchemy InvalidRequestError in different packages

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have 3 files in separate packages as follows:

```
-- base
|  - class BaseDb(db.Model)
|
-- pkg1
|  - class A(BaseDb)
|
-- pkg2
|  - class B(BaseDb)

where db is initialized as: db = SQLAlchemy(app) in some other __init__.py

class A(BaseDb):
  __tablename__ = "a"
  x = relationship("B", back_populates="y")

class B(BaseDb):
  __tablename__ = "b"
  y = relationship("A", back_populates="x")
```

The following error is shown:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class A->x'. Original exception was: When initializing mapper mapped class Loan->loans, expression 'B' failed to locate a name ("name 'B' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'A'> class after both dependent classes have been defined
```

When all of BaseDb, A, and B are defined in the same package, this works fine so the relationship is okay. A lot of older posts suggest using `declarative_base`, but this is also explicitly called by `SQLAlchemy` in its init while initializing `Model`.

I understand that this error is being thrown because B hasn't been loaded yet when A is executed. Any ideas on how to get this working? I would like to avoid putting them all in the same package to allow better modularity.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046039/sqlalchemy-import-tables-with-relationships

Answer (score 0):

It's not due to "executing A", but due to using the models (in a query) before they're all loaded. Using them is what triggers [mapper configuration](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.configure_mappers). One way to ensure that all the models are loaded before they get used for the first time is to have the parent module/package (of `pkg1` and `pkg2`) import all the models in its `__init__.py`, and so when you import one model, they all get pulled in.